# openssl_encrypt with a IV of 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF with encryption mode bf-cbc

Tags: php, delphi, php-openssl

I'm using a third party software, that creates key in blowfish in encryption mode CBC and an IV of 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF. How can I pass an IV like this to openssl_encrypt? The encoding of the source string is windows 1252.

Im using PHP 7.3 with UTF-8.

This are my current attempts:

```
$data = utf8_decode('12345678');

// if(strlen($data) % 8)
//   $data = str_pad($data, strlen($data) + 8 - strlen($data) % 8, "\0");

$opts = OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING;

if(defined('OPENSSL_DONT_ZERO_PAD_KEY'))
  $opts = $opts | OPENSSL_DONT_ZERO_PAD_KEY;

echo openssl_encrypt($data, 'bf-cbc', utf8_decode('my-secret-key'), $opts, hex2bin('FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF')) . '<br />';

$opts = OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING;

echo base64_encode(utf8_decode(openssl_encrypt($data, 'bf-cbc', utf8_decode('my-secret-key'), $opts, hex2bin('FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF')))) . '<br />';
```

The result always differ. The other end is using "Delphi Encryption Compendium Part I-III". I cannot change the way the other software creates the encrypted data. The sourcecode of the version the Delphi software uses can be found here: https://github.com/winkelsdorf/DelphiEncryptionCompendium/releases/tag/1

The Delphi function looks like:

```
function BlowfishEncryptStr(const InStr, Password: string;
  var OutStr: string; Format: Integer = -1): Boolean;
var
  Cipher: TCipher_Blowfish;

begin
  Cipher := TCipher_Blowfish.Create(Password, nil);

  try
    try
      Cipher.Mode := cmCBC;
      OutStr := Cipher.CodeString(InStr, paEncode, Format);
      Result := True;
    except
      Result := False;
    end;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(Cipher);
  end;
end;
```

The function is called with this parameters:

```
BlowfishEncryptStr('12345678', 'my-secret-key');
```

I tried the IV of 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF because it seems so, that this is the default of the Delphi Encryption Compendium in this case. I've tried to pass 0x0000000000000000 also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The initialization vector is just binary data - no need to use integers. So the answer is simply: `$sIv= "\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF";`.

The rest is pretty unclear: what does "result always differ" mean? Make sure the Delphi program always produces the same output (otherwise it uses initializations you're yet not aware of or does more than your script does). Your PHP script should always produce the same output per execution, even though the second output makes no sense at all (UTF decoding on binary data - you even forgot the "8").

Comment: The result in PHP differs from the one in Delphi. Is there anything else I can configure in PHP for bf-cbc? There are more options in the docu, but they only seem to work with other encryption methods. I tried "\xFF..., but the result ist exacly the same as with my hex2bin.

Comment: I've clarified my original question and linked the source-code of the Delphi Part and added an example. Sorry, that I missed that. Thank you for your support.

Comment: I'm also unable to achieve expected output with DEC 3.0, not even using an IV (and avoiding all padding and text encoding issues). By using DEC 5.2 the output matches. I can only assume 3.0 has an incorrect implementation.

Comment: I've accepted your answer, because you are perfectly answering the main question. I thank you for your afford. So I think there are no more options in the php implementation to match the encryption of the Delphi Compendium 3.0.